# Table overlay in beamer on multiple rows and multiple columns

Tags: tables, beamer, animations

I want to show columns of a table dynamically. On the first frame I want to show only the first column without the last row. Then on the second frame only the first column with the last row too. Then the second and third columns with the same pattern. My MWE is given below. I'd highly appreciate it if someone helped me.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Introduction}

\begin{tabular}{c<{\onslide<2->}|c<{\onslide<3->}|c<{\onslide<4->}}
\hline 
$X_{i}$ & $X_{i}-\overline{X}$ & $\left(X_{i}-\overline{X}\right)^{2}$\tabularnewline
\hline 
$X_{1}$ & $X_{1}-\overline{X}$ & $\left(X_{1}-\overline{X}\right)^{2}$\tabularnewline
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$\tabularnewline
$X_{i}$ & $X_{i}-\overline{X}$ & $\left(X_{i}-\overline{X}\right)^{2}$\tabularnewline
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$\tabularnewline
$X_{n}$ & $X_{n}-\overline{X}$ & $\left(X_{n}-\overline{X}\right)^{2}$\tabularnewline
\hline 
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$ & $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-\overline{X}\right)=0$ & $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-\overline{X}\right)^{2}$\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array}
\let\Tiny\tiny
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\begin{document}
\frame{
\begin{tabular}{>{\onslide<1->}c        >{\onslide<3->}c        >{\onslide<5->}c}
A & B & C \\
1 & 2 & 3  \\
3 & 4 & 5  \\
\onslide<2->5 & \onslide<4-> 6 & \onslide<6-> 7
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain the role of `>` in `>{\onslide<1->}`? I also saw  people using `<{\onslide<1->}`.

Comment: > puts things right before, while < puts it right after.  See the documentation for the array package, or the latex wikibook